# Add new column while joining tables in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

dateframe 1: crimedf

```
scala> crimedf.show(5,false)
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---+
|lat       |lng        |desc                                                                               |zip  |title                  |timeStamp            |twp              |addr                      |e  |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---+
|40.2978759|-75.5812935|REINDEER CT & DEAD END;  NEW HANOVER; Station 332; 2015-12-10 @ 17:10:52;          |19525|EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY |2015-12-10 17:40:00.0|NEW HANOVER      |REINDEER CT & DEAD END    |1  |
|40.2580614|-75.2646799|BRIAR PATH & WHITEMARSH LN;  HATFIELD TOWNSHIP; Station 345; 2015-12-10 @ 17:29:21;|19446|EMS: DIABETIC EMERGENCY|2015-12-10 17:40:00.0|HATFIELD TOWNSHIP|BRIAR PATH & WHITEMARSH LN|1  |
|40.1211818|-75.3519752|HAWS AVE; NORRISTOWN; 2015-12-10 @ 14:39:21-Station:STA27;                         |19401|Fire: GAS-ODOR/LEAK    |2015-12-10 17:40:00.0|NORRISTOWN       |HAWS AVE                  |1  |
|40.116153 |-75.343513 |AIRY ST & SWEDE ST;  NORRISTOWN; Station 308A; 2015-12-10 @ 16:47:36;              |19401|EMS: CARDIAC EMERGENCY |2015-12-10 17:40:01.0|NORRISTOWN       |AIRY ST & SWEDE ST        |1  |
|40.251492 |-75.6033497|CHERRYWOOD CT & DEAD END;  LOWER POTTSGROVE; Station 329; 2015-12-10 @ 16:56:52;   |null |EMS: DIZZINESS         |2015-12-10 17:40:01.0|LOWER POTTSGROVE |CHERRYWOOD CT & DEAD END  |1  |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

**crimedf.registerTempTable("crimedf")**

dataframe 2: zipcode

```
scala> zipcode.show(5)
+---+----------+-----+---------+----------+--------+---+
|zip|      city|state| latitude| longitude|timezone|dst|
+---+----------+-----+---------+----------+--------+---+
|210|Portsmouth|   NH|43.005895|-71.013202|      -5|  1|
|211|Portsmouth|   NH|43.005895|-71.013202|      -5|  1|
|212|Portsmouth|   NH|43.005895|-71.013202|      -5|  1|
|213|Portsmouth|   NH|43.005895|-71.013202|      -5|  1|
|214|Portsmouth|   NH|43.005895|-71.013202|      -5|  1|
+---+----------+-----+---------+----------+--------+---+
```

**zipcode.registerTemptable("zipcode")**

> My requirement is :
>
> 1. Create a new column "problem" by extracting substring before ":" from column "title of table"crimedf"
> 2. join the 2 tables and group the columns "state" and "problem" and generate count.

I get the desired output when i generate a new table from the first table and joining this with the second table.

```
scala> val newcrimedf = sqlContext.sql("select substring_index(title,':',1) as problem, zip from crimedf")
newcrimedf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [problem: string, zip: int]

scala> newcrimedf.show(2)
+-------+-----+
|problem|  zip|
+-------+-----+
|    EMS|19525|
|    EMS|19446|
+-------+-----+
```

**newcrimedf.registerTempTable("newcrimedf")**

```
sqlContext.sql("select z.state, n.problem, count(*) as count 
from newcrimedf n 
JOIN zipcode z 
ON n.zip = z.zip 
GROUP BY z.state,n.problem 
ORDER BY count DESC").show
+-----+-------+-----+                                                           
|state|problem|count|
+-----+-------+-----+
|   PA|    EMS|44326|
|   PA|Traffic|29297|
|   PA|   Fire|13012|
|   AL|Traffic|    1|
|   TX|    EMS|    1|
+-----+-------+-----+
```

**How to generate the same output from the original first table("crimedf") without creating a second table "newcrimedf"?**

How to add a new column while joining?
Pls help.

I tried doing it, but its wrong.
Below is what I had tried:

```
sqlContext.sql("select z.state, c.problem, count(*) as count from 
(select zip, substring(title,':',1) problem from crimedf) c 
JOIN zipcode z ON c.zip = z.zip 
GROUP BY z.state,c.problem ORDER BY count desc").show
+-----+-------+-----+                                                           
|state|problem|count|
+-----+-------+-----+
|   PA|   null|86635|
|   TX|   null|    1|
|   AL|   null|    1|
+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: your query is perfect except for one mistake that instead of `substring_index` you used `substring`. :) see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

> > Create a new column "problem" by extracting substring before ":" from column "title of table"crimedf"

This can be achived using `withColumn` api and simple `split` function ( see the code below)

> > join the 2 tables and group the columns "state" and "problem" and generate count.

these can be achieved by using `join`, `groupBy` and `count` *aggregation* (see the code below)

Following code should work for you

```
crimedf.select("zip", "title")                    //selecting needed columns from crimedf
  .withColumn("problem", split($"title", ":")(0)) //generating problem column by splitting title column
  .join(zipcode, Seq("zip"))                      // joining with zipcode dataframe with zip column
  .groupBy("state", "problem")                   //grouping by state and problem
  .agg(count("state"))                           //counting the grouped data
  .show(false)
```

**Edited**

your sql query works perfect and gives the same result as the api used above. You just forgot to append `_index` in `substring`

```
sqlContext.sql("""select z.state, c.problem, count(*) as count from
              (select zip, substring_index(title,':',1) as problem from crimedf) c
                 JOIN zipcode z ON c.zip = z.zip
                 GROUP BY z.state,c.problem ORDER BY count desc""").show(false)
```

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan _Thanks_ but I need SQL query

Comment: didn't the answer helped you @Jayson?